# Why is threading used for sockets?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, networking, thread-safety

Ever since I discovered sockets, I've been using the nonblocking variants, since I didn't want to bother with learning about threading. Since then I've gathered a lot more experience with threading, and I'm starting to ask myself.. Why would you ever use it for sockets?

A big premise of threading seems to be that they only make sense if they get to work on their own set of data. Once you have two threads working on the same set of data, you will have situations such as:

```
if(!hashmap.hasKey("bar"))
{
  dostuff               // <-- meanwhile another thread inserts "bar" into hashmap
  hashmap[bar] = "foo"; // <-- our premise that the key didn't exist
                        //     (likely to avoid overwriting something) is now invalid
}
```

Now imagine hashmap to map remote IPs to passwords. You can see where I'm going. I mean, sure, the likelihood of such thread-interaction going wrong is pretty small, but it's still existent, and to keep one's program secure, you have to account for every eventuality. This will significantly increase the effort going into design, as compared to simple, single-threaded workflow.

I can completely see how threading is great for working on separate sets of data, or for programs that are explicitly optimized to use threading. But for the "general" case, where the programmer is only concerned with shipping a working and secure program, I can not find any reason to use threading over polling.

But seeing as the "separate thread" approach is extremely widespread, maybe I'm overlooking something. Enlighten me! :)

Comment: Using threads you can be handling two different connections on the server at the same time.  Otherwise you'll have to handle them sequentially.

Comment: Imagine a webserver that can only serve one http request at a time. Using treading the webserver will be able to handle more requests in parallel.

Comment: Yeah, services such as HTTP have the big advantage of being able to serve more or less unrelated requests. Where they do use the same dataset, they use databases, which have a builtin transaction model and are thus threadsafe. However, that is only one type of application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two common reasons for using threads with sockets, one good and one not-so-good:

The good reason:  Because your computer has more than one CPU core, and you want to make use of the additional cores.  A single-threaded program can only use a single core, so with a heavy workload you'd have one core pinned at 100%, and the other cores sitting unused and going to waste.

The not-so-good reason:  You want to use blocking I/O to simplify your program's logic -- in particular, you want to avoid dealing with partial reads and partial writes, and keep each socket's context/state on the stack of the thread it's associated with.  But you also want to be able to handle multiple clients at once, without slow client A causing an I/O call to block and hold off the handling of fast client B.

The reason the second reason is not-so-good is that while having one thread per socket seems to simplify the program's design, in practice it usually complicates it.  It introduces the possibility of race conditions and deadlocks, and makes it difficult to safely access shared data (as you mentioned).  Worse, if you stick with blocking I/O, it becomes very difficult to shut the program down cleanly (or in any other way effect a thread's behavior from anywhere other than the thread's socket), because the thread is typically blocked in an I/O call (possibly indefinitely) with no reliable way to wake it up.   (Signals don't work reliably in multithreaded programs, and going back to non-blocking I/O means you lose the simplified program structure you were hoping for)

In short, I agree with cib -- multithreaded servers can be problematic and therefore should generally be avoided unless you absolutely need to make use of multiple cores -- and even then it might be better to use multiple processes rather than multiple threads, for safety's sake.

Comment: If the client code is isolated request/rsponse, ie serving web pages from files and not a chat server, there is same chance of writing bad code as with any other server design and next-to no chance of races or deadlocks on anything since nothing is shared.  Shutting down the threads is usually a non-issue because the threads don't own anything that needs explicit release.  99.9% of all household threads can be just left for the OS to kill on process exit. OS are very, very good at stopping threads in any state, unlike the horrible, messy user code I see so often posted here.

Comment: Well, certainly on Windows anyway.  My multithreaded and IOCP servers on load test have no messy, tempramental, difficult-to-test, awkward, nasty, buggy thread-shutdown code at all.  I click on the little 'red cross' icon of my server and the OS wastes all the threads, sockets, buffers, pools, the lot in a flash with no aparrent effort, no matter whether the server is busy or idle, one core or 16.  Most problems arise because of FUD about 'cleanly shutting down' when it's not needed - the bug is actually attempting thread shutdown without the hardware intercore comms available to the OS.

Comment: @MartinJames I more or less agree, if all requests are entirely separate, there is no visible downside to threading.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks, that nicely sums up what I had been suspecting, and also the other answers/comments here. Use threading when you explicitly want to serve many requests at once, or when those threads will work on unrelated datasets.. Don't use threading otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest advantage of threads is to prevent the accumulated lag time from processing requests. When polling you use a loop to service every socket with a state change.  For a handful of clients, this is not very noticeable, however it could lead to significant delays when dealing with significantly large number of clients.

Assuming that each transaction requires some pre-processing and post processing (depending on the protocol this may be trivial amount of processing, or it could be relatively significant as is the case with BEEP or SOAP). The combined time to pre-process/post-process requests could lead to a backlog of pending requests.

For illustration purposes imagine that the pre-processing, processing, and post-processing stage of a request each consumes 1 microsecond so that the total request takes 3 microseconds to complete. In a single threaded environment the system would become overwhelmed if incoming requests exceed 334 requests per second (since it would take 1.002 seconds to service all requests received within a 1 second period of time) leading to a time deficit of 0.002 seconds each second.  However if the system were using threads, then it would be theoretically possible to only require 0.336 seconds * (0.334 for shared data access + 0.001 pre-processing + 0.001 post processing) of processing time to complete all of the requests received in a 1 second time period.

Although theoretically possible to process all requests in 0.336 seconds, this would require each request to have it's own thread. More reasonably would be to multiple the combined pre/post processing time (0.668 seconds) by the number of requests and divide by the number of configured threads.  For example, using the same 334 incoming requests and processing time, theoritically 2 threads would complete all requests in 0.668 seconds (0.668 / 2 + 0.334), 4 threads in 0.501 seconds, and 8 threads in 0.418 seconds.

If the highest request volume your daemon receives is relatively low, then a single threaded implementation with non-blocking I/O is sufficient, however if you expect occasionally bursts of high volume of requests then it is worth considering a multi-threaded model.

I've written more than a handful of UNIX daemons which have relatively low throughput and I've used a single-threaded for the simplicity.  However, when I wrote a custom netflow receiver for an ISP, I used a threaded model for the daemon and it was able to handle peak times of Internet usage with minimal bumps in system load average.